# Python BeautifulSoup Find Siblings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say I have a html table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tr>...
        </tr>
        <tr>...
        </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tr>...
        </tr>
        <tr>...
        </tr>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

I could locate the table tag. How could I find the first layer of table rows which are the son .. not the grandson of the table.

```
print table.findAll('tr') # would return All the trs under table which is not what I want.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<body>
    <table>
        <tr id="tr_1">
            <tr id="tr_1_1">..</tr>
            <tr id="tr_1_2">...</tr>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr_2">
            <tr id="tr_2_1">...</tr>
            <tr id="tr_2_2">...</tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>''', ['lxml','xml'])

for tr in soup.select('table > tr'):
    print(tr)
    print('---')
```

prints

```
<tr id="tr_1">
<tr id="tr_1_1">..</tr>
<tr id="tr_1_2">...</tr>
</tr>
---
<tr id="tr_2">
<tr id="tr_2_1">...</tr>
<tr id="tr_2_2">...</tr>
</tr>
---
```

**NOTE**: need [`lxml`](http://lxml.de).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer falsetru, I finally used find_all(..,recursive=FALSE,..) to do what I want. But yours works too. So answer accepted.